# Filter results subscribe() with keyvalue in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, ionic4

I would like to filter the results of a JSON file, I already retrieve the list of data with keyvalue. But I would like to retrieve only the results or parent equals null.

Example of the data present in the JSON file

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example name",
        "parent": null,
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example name",
        "parent": 12,
    }
}
```

Here is my data retrieved from a JSON file

```
this.http.get(api).subscribe((data) => {
    this.number = Object.keys(data).length;
    this.cats = data;
});
```

And here is the HTML which processes the received data

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let item of cats | keyvalue" size="6">
        {{ item.value['name'] }}
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: You mean you only want the results items where `parent` is `null`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it, only those where the parent is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json returned is an object, and you would need to convert it to array first. With that array, filter where its `parent` properties isn't `null`

```js
this.http.get(api).subscribe((data) => {
    //convert it to an array, ignoring the keys
    objList = Object.values(data) 
    // now filter
    this.cats = objList.filter(cat=>cat.parent !== null)
    // assign the length of array to this.number
    this.number = this.cats.length;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanations, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you can filter inside the subscribe function:

```
this.http.get(api).subscribe((data) => {
    this.number = Object.keys(data).length;
    this.cats = data.filter(d => d.parent === null);
});
```

Comment: Here is the error encountered if I put your solution -> Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: If I define data as an array or any I get the following error: -> data.filter is not a function